# Finding the coordinates (x,y,z) of vertices of a square plane rotated about its center point in P5 js

Tags: javascript, math, p5.js, polar-coordinates

I am recreating conic sections in P5.js and need to find the equation of a square plane.

I know the size of the square plane, and the rotation in each axis in degrees from its center point (as dictated by the P5 sliders).

I want to calculate the coordinates (x, y, z) of the four vertices of this square plane, given known values for rotation.

This is my P5 sketch.

https://editor.p5js.org/inglog/sketches/HsMUb8UPA

I want to use these coordinates to create an equation for the plane, in the form ax+by+cz+d=0

Once I have the vertices of the square, I will use this calculator to get the equation of the plane: https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1223596129)

Any advice on how to calculate the coordinates of the vertices of the plane, given a known rotation about its center point?

Is this related to conversion between Cylindrical and Cartesian Coordinates? I also wonder if this answer is connected to the solution ([Rotating vertices about point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26644833/rotating-vertices-about-point))

Thank you in advance for reading through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is a unique plane that goes through a given set of 3 (noncollinear) points, you don't need the vertices of the square in order to find an equation for the plane. You just need 3 random points on the plane.

Answer:

```
A = (0, slider.value(), 0)
B = (1, slider.value(), 0)
C = (0, slider.value() - sin(slider2.value()), cos(slider2.value()))
```

From here, you can get the plane equation as they describe on the site you gave:

```
AB = (1, 0, 0)
AC = (0, -sin, cos)
AB x AC = (0, -cos, -sin)
```

Equation:

```
0x - cos(slider2.value())*y - sin(slider2.value())*z + cos(slider2.value())*slider.value() = 0
```

simplifies to

```
cos(slider2.value())*(y - slider.value()) + sin(slider2.value())*z = 0
```

or

```
z = (slider.value() - y)/tan(slider2.value())
```

I'm about 99.9% sure this is the right equation. I used it to overlay points on the plane in your program, and it looked right.

How I got the three points:

We know that there will be one point at the center, which is on the y-axis. At this point, x=z=0 and `y=slider.value()`. So that is point A: `(0, slider.value(), 0)`.

We also know that the plane intersects the xy-plane in the line defined by `y=slider.value()`. So point B can be any point on this line, let's arbitrarily pick `(1, slider.value(), 0)`.

The third point is the hardest, since we can't have z=0, and we have to consider the angle. Starting at the center, let's walk one unit along the plane, keeping x=0 and moving in the positive z direction.
It's hard to convey that point over text, but this is a classic unit circle problem: x=0, and y, z are on a unit circle centered at point A: C = `(0, slider.value() - sin(slider2.value()), cos(slider2.value()))`.